# Show $2 \lt f(x) \lt 2.8$?

Tags: functions

I have a question about a function $f(x)$:
$$f(x) = -x + \frac{x^2}{x-2} - \frac{20}{x^2 + x - 6},\qquad x>2$$
simplifies to
$$f(x) = 2x + \frac{10}{x + 3},\qquad x>2$$
How would you show the range of $f(x)$ is $2 < f(x) < 2.8?$
Thank you.

Comment: I think it should be $$\frac{2x+10}{x+3}$$

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be $$\frac{2x+10}{x+3}=\frac{2(x+3)+4}{x+3}=2+\frac4{x+3}$$

As $\displaystyle x>2,x+3>5\implies0<\frac1{x+3}<\frac15$

Comment: based on what I calculated, he is correct.

Comment: @jonnytan999, Edited

Comment: ah! I was halfway through typing the answer when this came...

Comment: im not quite sure what you did with the (2x+10)/(x+3)   ?

Comment: ohh sorry, i see so is the range of the function what your answer is?

Comment: @user149550, if $0<\frac1{x+3}<\frac15,$ can't you find the range of $f(x)?$

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee im not really sure how to?

Comment: @user149550, multiply each side of $$0<\frac1{x+3}<\frac15$$ by $4$. Then add $2$ to each side

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee why would you do that?